# Bash - Is there a way to replace a bash command with parameters every time is typed with another parameter?

Tags: bash, hpc, slurm, nextflow

I am working on a HPC running slurm and CentOS. My workflow software (Nextflow v19.10.0) needs to execute this command

```
squeue --noheader -o %i %t -t all -u username
```

However, I have an error raises the following error

```
squeue: error: Unrecognized option: %
Usage: squeue [-A account] [--clusters names] [-i seconds] [--job jobid]  [-n name] [-o format] [-p partitions] [--qos qos] [--reservation reservation] [--sort fields] [--start]  [--step step_id] [-t states] [-u user_name] [--usage] [-L licenses] [-w nodes] [--federation] [--local] [--sibling]  [-ahjlrsv]
```

Is there a way to wrap the above command in my .bashrc file, so when ever Nextflow runs the command it would automatically turned into this, which I have tested to work on my cluster?

```
squeue --noheader -o "%i %t" -t all -u username
```

Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: `%i %t` is supposed to be a single argument to the `-o` option, so there's a configuration error here somewhere. How does `Nextflow` get that command?

Comment: This definitely sounds like something that would be fixed on the Nextflow side, and not kludged via bash

Answer (score 1):

If Nextflow is running `bash` (the shell you tagged this question for), **not** `/bin/sh` (which is more common, as it's what the `system()` library call in many languages invokes), you can do this in any enclosing shell:

```
# override *any* call to squeue with a very specific command that's known to work
squeue() {
  printf 'Ignoring old squeue arguments: ' >&2
  printf '%q ' "$@" >&2
  printf '\n' >&2
  command squeue --noheader -o '%i %t' -t all -u username
}
export -f squeue
```

However, that probably won't work: It's likely that Nextflow is actually using `sh` instead, so instead of using an exported function, you'll want to create a directory with a `squeue` executable script in it that then invokes the *real* `squeue` command. Thus:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf 'Ignoring old squeue arguments: ' >&2
printf '%q ' "$@" >&2
printf '\n' >&2

# FIXME: replace /usr/bin/squeue with the actual location of the real command 
exec /usr/bin/squeue --noheader -o '%i %t' -t all -u username
```